# How to autostart an application on Touch device?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, services, ubuntu-sdk, autostart

What if you want to distribute some daemons in ubuntu-click packages? What is the preferred way to start them on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background things are called *helpers*. For example: downloader, media player, install helper.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Specifications/ApplicationConfinement#Helpers_and_trusted_helpers

> Apps may want want access to various other data or services, such as Contacts, Calendar, Location, Sensors, etc. This access should happen via an out of process helper and the preferred communication mechanism with out of process helpers is DBus. In this manner, AppArmor policy groups can be defined for these helpers using standard AppArmor DBus rules, etc. These type of helpers do not need any modification-- apps are either allowed to use them or not, and this is decided by AppArmor.

Apps are stopped and killed without mercy:

[TX Linux Fest 2015 - Ted Gould - Ubuntu Phone: Application Lifecycle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5iY2NgaBeY)

They shouldn't do the hard work.